# Convert rss pubDate to EST in .NET

Tags: .net, rss, date-format

I am trying to convert the pubDate in the Rss to EST. If you look at the links posted below, they have different timezones. Is there a function which takes any type of dateformat and convert to EST ?

http://rss.cnn.com/rss/cnn_topstories.rss

http://www.cricinfo.com/rss/content/story/feeds/0.rss

http://feeds.latimes.com/latimes/entertainment?format=xml

http://newsrss.bbc.co.uk/rss/newsonline_world_edition/business/rss.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [ConvertTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.converttime.aspx) method. For example:

```
var s = "Mon, 21 Dec 2009 14:09:45 GMT";
var date = DateTime.Parse(s, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var est = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
var estDate = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(date, est);
```

Comment: He'll still need to parse the strings.

Comment: `DateTime.Parse("Mon, 21 Dec 2009 09:52:27 EST")` fails.

Comment: Yes, an RFC 822 formatted datetime parser will be needed (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/284775/how-do-i-parse-and-convert-datetimes-to-the-rfc-822-date-time-format)

Comment: Darin, It works Like Magic. Thank you Very much for all of your efforts.