# How do I parse an RFC822 date in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, parsing, rfc822

I have the following datetime string as returned to me by the Twitter API:

> "Thu Apr 26 11:38:36 +0000 2012"

I need to convert this to a `DateTime` object so I call `ParseExact` with a custom format specifier:

```
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
DateTime publishDate = DateTime.ParseExact(tweet["created_at"].ToString(), "ddd MMM dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy", provider);
```

However, this raise a `FormatException` exception for any variant of `z`, `zz` or `zzz` for the time zone:

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Looking at the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) it's clear that that format specifier is expecting the time zone to be in the format `zz:zz` where there is a colon in the time zone to delimit the hours and minutes.

I've checked other questions on Stack Overflow like:

- [How do I parse and convert DateTime’s to the RFC 822 date-time format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/284775/how-do-i-parse-and-convert-datetimes-to-the-rfc-822-date-time-format)
- [Parsing an RFC822-Datetime in .NETMF 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2985707/parsing-an-rfc822-datetime-in-netmf-4-0)

and none of them really help.

Is there a time zone specifier I can use that will correctly parse this format?

Comment: Curious, I setup a test using your exact code without error.  Well, except that I don't have the `tweet` field, of course, I just used the date string verbatim.

Comment: @DonBoitnott - eh? Which version of .NET are you using?

Comment: Weird.. This doesn't throw any exception on my computer (VS 2008) (x86) (.NET 4.5) It doesn't throw also in [`Ideone`](http://ideone.com/mKywiy)

Comment: Test app is targeting 4.5 I think

Comment: @DonBoitnott - Ah. I'm on .NET 4.

Comment: I retargeted to 4.0 full and still no error.

Comment: Console application, targeting fw 4, runs your code perfectly (was 4.5, I re-targeted it. I'm on VS2012). Are you 100% sure about the contents of your "tweet[]" field ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Really silly this one.

The problem was the hour specifier. I'd used "hh" which is for 12 hour clock times. For 24 hour times I should have used "HH".

Note the subtle difference.

Changing that it all works as expected.

Comment: I think the answer here is much better than your way of doing it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/284775/how-do-i-parse-and-convert-datetime-s-to-the-rfc-822-date-time-format

Comment: @DermFrench - that question is a more general one. With this I had a very specific problem which had a very specific cause - albeit one that could be quite common to make.

Comment: I just assumed the parsing in the other answer would work in your case as well - didn't test it.