# Format 2 strings to RSS PubDate

Tags: c#, rss, pubdate

ive got 2 strings, date:"27.03.11 " and time:"15:04", which id like to format as a PubDate elemnt for a rss file like Fri, 18 Nov 2005 19:12:30 GMT.
How can i do this in c sharp?

Comment: First, parse both into the same DateTime and use that DateTime to generate your result string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following steps:

- *Parse* the date and time strings into one `DateTime` variable. Use the [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx) static method for this.
- *Convert* the datetime to GMT using the methods of the [TimeZone class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe5cd9e6.aspx) (if desired---I don't think this is mandatory according to the RSS specification).
- *Format* this variable into a string using the [DateTime.ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tostring.aspx) method. The following MSDN pages will help you choose the correct format string based on your needs:

  - [Standard Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx)
  - [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Since RSS requires dates to be in the RFC 822 format, the following related SO question might help you with the last step:

- [How do I parse and convert DateTime’s to the RFC 822 date-time format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/284775/how-do-i-parse-and-convert-datetimes-to-the-rfc-822-date-time-format)

**EDIT:** For the first step, have a look at this example:

```
var s = "27.03.11 15:04"; 
var dtm = DateTime.ParseExact(s, @"dd.MM.yy HH\:mm", null);
```

(The `\:` ensures that `:` is seen as a literal `:` rather than a culture-specific time separator.)

Comment: Can u help me withe the first part?
Itried the following example from a tutorial but always get the error "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
            String MyString;
            MyString = "1999-09-01 21:34 PM";
            //MyString = "1999-09-01 21:34 p.m.";  //Depends on your regional settings

            DateTime MyDateTime;
            MyDateTime = new DateTime();
            MyDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(MyString, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm tt", null);

Comment: That date doesn't make sense: If it's 24hour time, you don't need am or pm. I've added an example for the first part to my answer.

Comment: @kojoma: PS: Don't trust that tutorial, it's bad code (for example, there's no need to set MyDateTime to "new DateTime()" before filling it with ParseExact).