# Unable to parse string to DateTime

Tags: .net, casting, string-to-datetime

I have this string:

```
Fri, 13 Jan 2012 04:26:42 PST
```

I tries to parse it like that:

```
DateTime.TryParse("Fri, 13 Jan 2012 04:26:42 PST", out date)
```

Or like that:

```
Convert.ToDateTime("Fri, 13 Jan 2012 04:26:42 PST")
```

And it throws to me:

```
MESSAGE: The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index 26.
```

Any idea what is wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: `PST` is not recognized as a valid part of a `DateTime` string.

Comment: It is not in a recognized format. Timezones that are recognized in strings for parsing would have the format `+0700` or `-00:30`, for example. The .NET framework does not recognize named timezones like `PST` or `GMT`.

Comment: So how to handle it? Replace the PST to -08:00?

Comment: That would be one approach. That's how I answered.

Comment: Checkout the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/284775/29407

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With named timezones, you can create a dictionary that maps the names to the actual timezone difference in the format recognized - then, use this dictionary to replace named timezones with their recognized format.

At this point you will have a string that can be parsed by the framework.

```
Dictionary<string,string> namedToActualTZ = new Dictionary<string,string>();
namedToActualTZ.Add("PST", "-0800");
```

Answer (score 0):

its impossible to do it by default function such as , convert , format .. etc.you should write a function to parse it manualy.in it ,extract the weekday & time & date ... then create a valid date string or directly a date variable.