# Parse DateTime from string c#

Tags: c#, datetime

I have date that I get from incoming API call: `Wed, 6 Mar 2019 14:39:49 +0300`

I need to parse this string to DateTime. For this I'm using the following code:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("Wed, 6 Mar 2019 14:39:49 +0300", 
                     new string[] { "ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzzz" },
                     CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal);
```

But as a result I have error:

> String 'Wed, 6 Mar 2019 14:39:49 +0300' was not recognized as a valid
>   DateTime.

What am I doing wrong? How can I resolve this?

Comment: It seems like the problem is with the single digit (6) doesn't match the `dd` pattern. "06" should probably work

Comment: 'Long date format' is not a good fit for APIs, it would be better to use ISO8601 formats is at all possible, which is language independent.  If your code is running in a non-English locale, then it will not parse correctly.  If you have any control over the API, I would recommend you fix it.

Comment: FYI: Not directly related to your problem, but you don't need to use a string array if you want to use/provide only a single date format string...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I see 2 things;

1. You should use [`d` specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#the-d-custom-format-specifier) instead of `dd` specifier since your single digit day number does *not* have a [leading zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leading_zero).
2. There is no `zzzz` as a custom format specifier. You should use [`zzz` specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#the-zzz-custom-format-specifier) instead.

```
DateTime.ParseExact("Wed, 6 Mar 2019 14:39:49 +0300", 
                     new string[] { "ddd, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz" },
                     CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal);
```

But honestly, if your strings have a [UTC Offset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) value, I would suggest parse it to [`DateTimeOffset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset?view=netframework-4.7.2) instead since a `DateTime` instance does not have offset part and using `zzz` specifiers is not recomended as stated on MSDN.

> With `DateTime` values, the "zzz" custom format specifier represents the
>   signed offset of the local operating system's time zone from UTC,
>   measured in hours and minutes. It does not reflect the value of an
>   instance's `DateTime.Kind` property. **For this reason, the "zzz" format
>   specifier is not recommended for use with DateTime values.**

To parse `DateTimeOffset`,

```
DateTimeOffset.ParseExact("Wed, 6 Mar 2019 14:39:49 +0300", 
                           new string[] { "ddd, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz" },
                           CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal);
```

Now you can use it's [`.DateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.datetime?view=netframework-4.7.2) and/or [`.Offset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.offset?view=netframework-4.7.2) properties separately if you want.

Comment: This will fail when the day has 2 digits

Comment: @haim770, why would you think so? Have you tested it?

Comment: @haim770 I don't think so since [`d` specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#the-d-custom-format-specifier) accepts values from `1` to `31` and a single-digit day is without leading zero.

Comment: Sorry. My mistake

Comment: @haim770 is right, just checked that, replaced 6 with 16 and it fails.

Comment: @A.Gladkiy It fails because you need to make sure your `ddd` (the weekday) matches the date

Comment: @A.Gladkiy If 6th is Wednesday, 16th sould be Saturday, not wednesday. That's why changing day value only creates an date that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Change "ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzzz" to "ddd, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzzz"

```
DateTime.ParseExact("Wed, 6 Mar 2019 14:39:49 +0300", 
                     new string[] { "ddd, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzzz" },
                     CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal);
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for

```
DateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact("Wed, 6 Mar 2019 14:39:49 +0300",
                                      "ddd, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz",
                                      CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                                      DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal);
```

Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10426999/4373895 This would also help you.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Datetime.ParseExact function just like below code withh help you. One thing needs to be changed is instead of dd MMM yyyy use d MMM yyyy.

```
DateTime.ParseExact("Wed, 6 Mar 2019 14:39:49 +0300", "ddd, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal);
```

Answer (score 1):

d MMM yyyy instead of ddd MMM yyyy

```
date = DateTime.ParseExact("Wed, 6 Mar 2019 14:39:49 +0300", "ddd, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal);
```

Answer (score 0):

The format for the UTC offset is `zzz` not `zzzz` and expects it to have a colon (`:`) to separate the hours from the minutes (such as `+03:00`). As well as the `dd` is for leading zero day of month but you have a single digit for the day of month. In that case use `d`.

Comment: unfortunately it didn't help and I can't add colon (`:`) as it's 3-rd party service.

Comment: @A.Gladkiy you can do some preprocessing on the string.

Comment: @DanielA.White Actually `zzz` specifier _can_ parse without `:` as well. From wikipedia: "It is generally shown in the format `±[hh]:[mm]`, `±[hh][mm]`, or `±[hh]`". That colon is not mandatory as far as I can see.

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime time = Convert.ToDateTime("Wed, 6 Mar 2019 14:39:49 +0300");
string ti = time.ToString(@"ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzzz");
```